# Ros package for sensor Fusion (IMU and Pressure) data?

Tags: ros, velocity, sensor-fusion, imu, pressure

Im looking for a ROS package (KF or UKF or EKF) that can fuse IMU and Pressure Sensors data. I would like to have 6x6 estimated Velocity matrices( linear and angular) from the IMU and Pressure sensor data. IMU is 9  DOF ( orientation, angular_velocity and linear_acceleration) and the Pressure. Barometer(pressure sensor data) can be use for the underwater robot as assume the sea (water ) level is same(constant) and the pressure suppose to maintain same value my linear movement of the underwater robot (vehicle). Is it possible to use this package to fuse this IMU and Pressure data to obtain estimated Velocity (linear and angular)?

If no existing ROS package (that serve as velocity observer) and fuse IMU and Pressure data, then any other code or help that I can use and implemented in ROS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) as it will take imu and 3D/2D odometry. You will just need to convert the pressure into an odom message yourself. Otherwise, [the hector localization](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_localization) package supports pressure as an input type by default.